# What does writing "\r\027[1A\027[K" to stdout do?

Tags: shell, ocaml, ascii

I came across some code for chat application in the terminal (in OCaml) and swa this string (in ASCII?) "\r\027[1A\027[K" being printed into the terminal before a new user message is printed to the terminal.

I have tried googling literals one by one, so I know that "\r" stands for cartridge return and `\027` for ESC in ASCII, but what does "[1A" and "[K" do? What character encoding is this?

And finally, what is the aggregate effect of this command?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: It's mind-boggling that the source code doesn't come with any hint of what this might be doing. It's pretty easy to create a function named `move_up_and_delete_line` or whatever. There's no excuse for writing such cryptic source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` introduces a control sequence.   `A` is the control sequence for "cursor up", and `[1A` moves the cursor up 1 line. `K` erases a line.  So `\x1b[1A\x1b[K` moves up one line and deletes it (replaces it with spaces).

Of course, that is only valid if the terminal that receives that string recognizes the control sequences.  Not all do.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

I'm not sure what 027 is trying to do.  It seems like an error and should have been 033.

Comment: thank you! but why are the escapes needed?

Comment: and how can I check if any particular terminal recognizes control sequences?

Comment: Use `tput`!  To know if your terminal recognizes sequences, you can either inspect the terminfo/termcap data, or eyball it.

Comment: OCaml numeric escapes starting with 0 are in decimal. So "\027" is in fact the escape character.